# Is it considered a bad practice to request data from the server in a service constructor in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service

I have an angular service that is responsible for representing a collection of employees (that happens to be stored on the database normally). I hear that it is bad code smell to do a `$http.get` request inside the service's class's constructor. What I have been told is that I am supposed to inject the dependency that allows you to collect the relevant data but isn't that what I'm doing by using `$http`, using dependency injection?

So is it bad form to simply do `var employees = $http.get('employees')` from the server?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you going to retrieve employees every now and then, or is it simply a one time job ??\

Comment: @TechMa9iac Right now one time. Only one person can access the app and CRUD at a time (no need to synch). I may need to extend it to support multiple people in the future (depending on the management). Also, I may need to limit (in the future) the amount of data that is loaded onto the client side. So I may need to load more records, during pagination navigation and search by substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service is your model, all call to your server should be centralized in services.

If i start from your example you should have an "EmployeeService"
And in it a function like that : (don't forget to inject $q and $http services)

```
me = this;
me.cacheEmployee = null;
me.getEmployees = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if(me.cacheEmployee != null){
        deferred.resolve(me.cacheEmployee);
    }else{
       $http.get('urlToEmployee').success(function(result){
           me.cacheEmployee = result;
           deferred.resolve(me.cacheEmployee);
       });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
};
me.forceLoadEmployee = function(){ // after each CreateUpdateDelete operations
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('urlToEmployee').success(function(result){
        me.cacheEmployee = result;
        deferred.resolve(me.cacheEmployee);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

And in the controller of the page you want to display your employees (don't forget to inject EmployeeService)

```
EmployeeService.getEmployees().then(function(result){
   $scope.employees = result;
});
```

You use asynchronous call, you can't think in procedural way to resolve your problem.

A basic doc about promise : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

I hope my answer will fit you.

Have a nice day !

Edit : now you have a list of employee in cache, the call will be launched to the server only the first time.

Comment: This is a good example but does not necessarily really help me. My service is supposed to be a model of a collection of employees in the sense that I want to use getters and setters for specific fields. I don't want to load these fields each time. I want to download all the relevant data once (like @ TechMa9iac said) and then just allow the controller to access that data. But this appears to be a step in the right direction. +1